# How to fit multiple curves into one function using python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a function containing 2 dependent variables (x1 and x2), 2 parameters (a and b), producing 1 independent variable (y).

Below the link are experimenetal values in nested arrays where column 1 is x1, column 2 is x2 and column 3 is y.

http://pastebin.com/j1LA9JcW

I used `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to solve for parameters 'a' and 'b'

The problem is python somehow thinks that the data needs to be fitted back to the initial point. As described in the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqcOR.jpg

Specifically I used this function to solve for the parameters.

```
scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x1 and x2 in one array,y, guess parameters)
```

I do not exactly know why it is like the graph as shown but could it be the x1 and x2 array needs to separate into 2 arrays, because there are 2 curves? If so, what is the way to do so?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you performed the curve-fitting correctly, but when you plot your results try to use a scatter instead of line, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot( x, y, 'bo' ) # plot each point in blue 'o's
plt.show()
```

at the moment your graph is connecting all the points but your list of points isn't sorted